# Fails to Implement orderedmodel

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement orderedmodel from here: https://github.com/kirelagin/django-orderedmodel

But it fail with DatabaseError `Exception Value: no such column: qrgame_place.order`

The documentation says nothing about that the model should contain the field `order` so I suppose the parent class is supposed to implement that field? [EDIT: Yeah, it is. Tried that...]

Here are some of the important snippets from the django files:

```
# models.py

import hashlib
import random
from django.db import models
from orderedmodel import OrderedModel


class Place(OrderedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    clue = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self):
        # Need a secret identifier for url. Using a hashed name (which
        # is also secret until found. So no need to obscure more)
        if not self.id:
            hashsrc = self.name.encode('utf-8')
            self.code = unicode(hashlib.sha1(hashsrc).hexdigest()[:7])
        super(Place, self).save()



# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from qrgame.models import Place
from orderedmodel import OrderedModelAdmin


class PlaceAdmin(OrderedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'clue', 'reorder']

admin.site.register(Place, PlaceAdmin)



# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'orderedmodel',
    'qrgame',
)
```

I have ran `python manage.py syncdb` after implemented this.

Any idea what's wrong? (Django version is (1, 4, 1, 'final', 0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syncdb` can't alter existing tables at the moment. You can do the following:

- drop table manually and than run `syncdb`
- run `manage.py reset qrgame` but all data of the qrgame app will be lost
- use any existing django db migration solutions, like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/)
- manually add column to the table (hints: `manage.py dbshell` will give you db REPL. You can get column definition from `manage.py sqlall qrgame`
- [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) and [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) commands can be helpful for saving and restoring existing data between schema changes

Comment: Though! That was a simple fix :-/ I removed the database and repopulated it.